# Android chrome doesn't play local sound file in html

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, audio

I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test sound</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="file:///sdcard/Music/beep.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    </audio><br />
</body>
</html>
```

When I store this file to the tablet (Lenovo A7600 Android 4.4.2) and open it in chrome (45.0.2454.94) the sound is playing.

But, when I store the html on my web server and try to open it in chrome, the audio control is visible but no sound us playing, even not if I cklick the play button.

Is there a restriction in android chrome like in desktop chrome "Not allowed to load local resource"? And, is there a way to remove this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is called sandbox:

> Sandboxing
>
> Sandboxing helps prevent malware from installing itself on your
>   computer or using what happens in one browser tab to affect what
>   happens in another. The sandbox adds an additional layer of protection
>   to your browser by protecting against malicious web pages that try to
>   leave programmes on your computer, monitor your web activities or
>   steal private information from your hard drive.

You can't do anything about this as it's an important security feature of all browsers to prevent execution of files or reading private data of the user.